# O que é uma "nota à imprensa"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O que significa ***nota à imprensa***? Lendo um artigo vi essa expressão:

> Em nota à imprensa, Rodrigues disse que tem "um passado limpo e uma vida decente" e afirmou nunca ter se envolvido em escândalos. [Veja mais](https://noticias.uol.com.br/ultimas-noticias/agencia-estado/2020/10/14/pf-encontra-dinheiro-na-cueca-de-vice-lider-do-governo-bolsonaro.htm?cmpid=copiaecola)

Procurei na internet e parece que é alguma coisa formal publicada no jornal. Alguma explicação?

Comment: Acredito que o verbo esteja omitido: Em nota enviada à.... Em nota informada à... Em nota transmitida à...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma ***nota à imprensa*** é uma notícia curta (uma *nota*) que uma pessoa, empresa ou outra organização envia aos jornais e revistas (a imprensa) e também às televisões e rádios. A imprensa não tem qualquer obrigação de publicar essas notas na íntegra (ou as televisões e rádios de as ler), e creio que nem é muito comum fazerem-no. Mas podem, se as acharem interessantes, usá-las nas suas notícias. Por exemplo, no excerto que tu apresentas do artigo, o jornalista citou parte da nota, e no resto do artigo cita ainda outras partes.

A ***nota à imprensa*** é também conhecida por *nota **de** imprensa*, *comunicado de imprensa* ou *comunicado à imprensa*. A [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunicado_de_imprensa) tem um artigo sobre o assunot. Corresponde ao inglês [*press release* (Wikipedia em inglês com artigo muito desenvolvido)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_release). Segundo o artigo na [Wikipédia em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comunicado_de_imprensa) também se usa *press release* ou simplesmente *release* em português (imagino que no Brasil, porque não me lembro de ter lido ou ouvido em Portugal; mas posso andar distraído).

A versão com***à*** é mais autoexplicativa. A preposição ***de*** serve para tudo e mais alguma coisa, de modo que em *nota/comunicado **de** imprensa* uma pessoa que não saiba não compreende qual é a relação entre *nota/comunicado* e *imprensa*. Com a preposição *a*, subentende-se que a nota foi enviada **à** imprensa: a pessoa ou departamento de relações públicas de uma empresa envia a nota aos jornais, às televisões e a outras organizações noticiosas.

Comment: Jacinto, só quero aqui deixar a nota que *"comunicado de impressa"* e *"nota de imprensa"* costumam ser usados com significados diferentes nos jornais. Um comunicado de imprensa normalmente é um texto longo, elaborado, com várias ideias; enquanto a nota à imprensa é curta. Sei isto de muitos anos a ler os jornais, em qua "nota à imprensa" geralmente se resume a uma frase enquanto "comunicado de imprensa" é sempre resumido de modo mais extenso. (Quem for formado em comunicação empresarial saberá as definições mais rigorosas.) Uma nota normalmente é só um facto e pouco mais.

Comment: @bad_coder, pois, *nota* sugere texto curto, mas eu encontrei vários artigos que usam o os dois termos sem distinção, e encontro "notas à imprensa" (por exemplo [esta](https://www2.anac.gov.br/imprensa/nota130910.asp)) e "comunicados" (por exemplo, [este](https://www2.anac.gov.br/imprensa/nota130910.asp), da mesma instituição que a "nota") com a mesma extensão; não são exemplos únicos.

Answer (score 1):

Para analisar a frase devemos começar por reparar que **`à`** é uma **contracção**,

> **à**
>
> Contracção da preposição a com o artigo ou pronome a (ex.: era uma versão muito semelhante à que ouvimos naquele dia; não respondeu acertadamente à pergunta; bacalhau à minhota; polvo à lagareiro).
>
> ["a", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa](https://dicionario.priberam.org/a)

Portanto a expressão "nota à imprensa" deve ser vista como:

> nota a a imprensa

Sim, com **dois `a`**! O primeiro `a` é **preposição** e o segundo `a` é **artigo** definido.

A função de uma preposição é:

> Chamam-se PREPOSIÇÕES as palavras inariáveis que relacionam dois termos de uma oração, de tal modo que o sentido do primeiro (ANTECEDENTE) é completamente explicado ou complementado pelo segundo (CONSEQUENTE).
>
> in *"Nova gramática do português contemporáneo"*, Lindley Cintra e Celso Cunha.

A relação preposicional que o `a` tem na frase é de movimento, portanto a contracção `à` leva o sentido de `movimento de x para y`, do antecedente para o consequente, da nota para a imprensa.